# Remove whitespace from all filenames in directory - Java

Tags: java, image, directory, whitespace, rename

I have directory of images and I want to rename the files by removing all of the whitespace in the name.

So let's say I have a file name called " f il ena me .png" (I plan on checking all of the file names in the directory). How might I remove all of the spaces and rename the image so that the correct file name (for this specific case) is "filename.png".

So far I have tried the following code and it actually deletes the image in the directory (I'm testing it on one image in the directory currently).

```
public static void removeWhiteSpace (File IBFolder) {
    // For clarification:
    // File IBFolder = new File("path/containing/images/folder/here");
    String oldName;
    String newName;
    String temp;
    for (File old : IBFolder.listFiles()) {
        oldName = old.getName();
        temp = oldName.replaceAll(" ", "");
        // I have also tried:
        // temp = oldName.replaceAll("//s", "");
        temp = temp.split(".png")[0];
        newName = temp + ".png";
        System.out.println(newName);
        old.renameTo(new File(newName));
    }
}
```

Comment: please don't let variable names start with an upper-case character - its against JAVA naming conventions.

Comment: It s the printed filename correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it doesn't delete the images, but moves them to your current working directory and renames it to `newName`, but since `newName` is missing a path information, it will rename / move it to "./" (from wherever you run your program).

I think you have a bug in these lines:

```
    temp = temp.split(".png")[0];
    newName = temp + ".png";
```

"." is a wilcard character and lets say your file is called "some png.png", `newName` would be "som.png", because "some png.png".replaceAll(" ", "").split(".png") results in "som".

If by any reason you need the String.split() method, please properly quote the ".":

```
    temp = temp.split("\\.png")[0];
```

Comment: Gotcha! You were right. I haven't been paying attention to the current directory I'm working in. Whoops! Thanks for the help. I'll tinker with it and make sure I give it the path name. I understand your point about the upper-case variable names and I'm a little torn to rename it to lower case since IB stands for something. I'll probably rewrite the program once complete and alternate var names that make more sense.

Comment: And what's this "temp.split(".png") about anyway?

Comment: You're right. I got my solution. I'll post it as an answer to my question in a minute. Thanks again for the help. I forgot I had a bug there before I posted this.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring naming conventions (which I intend to fix later) here is the solution I finalized.

```
public static void removeWhiteSpace (File IBFolder) {
    // For clarification:
    // File IBFolder = new File("path/containing/images/folder/here");
    String oldName;
    String newName;
    for (File old : IBFolder.listFiles()) {
        oldName = old.getName();
        if (!oldName.contains(" ")) continue;
        newName = oldName.replaceAll("\\s", "");

        // or the following code should work, not sure which is more efficient
        // newName = oldName.replaceAll(" ", "");

        old.renameTo(new File(IBFolder + "/" + newName));
    }
}
```

Comment: you still forgot to escape the "." - it should be .split("\\.png") !

Comment: Got it! Terribly sorry about the bad code. I just started getting into Java 5 days ago I believe and I'm getting used to some of the small things. I appreciate the help. I found it unnecessary to spilt it as you mentioned above. But I did need to know about the
    .split("\\.png")
you mentioned for another point in my program.